# Loading images for drawing on canvas in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawimage

I have been trying to teach my 11 year old son to program in javascript, but being a java programmer myself, I'm not too sure to get the below to work.  The code, as written, displays a simple block in the `drawRocket` method, but my son wants it to display an image of a rocket instead.  However, if I comment in the `drawImage` method and comment out the `drawRect` method, then it doesn't display the rocket image.

I understand, from reading the various threads on this topic on stackoverflow, that the issue is that javascript doesn't load images synchronously, and therefore I need to write the code with an onload listener on the rocket image object.  However, I tried replacing the `main()` call with this code (and removing the two lines from the main method):

```
var rocket = new Image();
rocket.onload = main(rocket);
rocket.src = "rocket.jpg";
```

And it still didn't work.  I tried various other things, but nothing seems to work for me.  The rocket.jpg image is fine.

No doubt the answer is very simple, but I'm still struggling after 2 hours.  Any help please?

Thanks!

C.

P.S. Coal powered rockets are the next big thing ;)

```
<head>
<script>

function drawSky(ctx) {
   ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,50)";
   ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
}

function drawGround(ctx) {
   ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(150,150,127)";
   ctx.fillRect(0, 295, 300, 5);
}

function drawRocket(ctx, rocket, height) {
   var drawHeight = 250 - height*2;
   if (drawHeight > 245)
      drawHeight = 245;

//   ctx.drawImage(rocket, 140, drawHeight, 20, 50);

   ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";
   ctx.fillRect(140, drawHeight, 20, 50);
}

function drawExplosion(ctx, size) {
   ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,102,0)";
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(150, 295, size, 180*Math.PI/180, 360*Math.PI/180);
   ctx.fill();
}

function drawCoalBar(ctx, coal) {

   ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
   ctx.fillText("COAL", 10, 25);   


   if (coal <= 15)
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";  
   else if (coal <= 30)
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,125,0)";
   else
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,225,0)";


   ctx.fillRect(45, 15, coal*4, 10);   
   ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
   ctx.strokeRect(45, 15, 60*4, 10);   

}

function main() {

var canvas = document.getElementById('gameview');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var rocket = new Image();
rocket.src = "rocket.jpg";

drawSky(ctx);
drawGround(ctx);

var name = prompt("What is your name?");
document.write("<p>Good luck Captain " + name + "!</p>");

var height = 100;
var speed = 0;
var coal = 60;
var burn = 0;
var gravity = 5;
var maxSpeedForSafeLanding = 8;

document.write("<p>");
document.write("The maximum speed for a safe landing is " + maxSpeedForSafeLanding + "m/s.");
document.write("<p>");

while (height > 0)
{
   document.write("Burn: " + burn + "kg");
   document.write(" - Height: " + height + "m");
   document.write(" - Speed: " + speed + "m/s");
   document.write(" - Coal: " + coal + "kg");
   document.write("<br />"); 

   drawSky(ctx);
   drawGround(ctx);
   drawRocket(ctx, rocket, height);
   drawCoalBar(ctx, coal);   


   // Ask for ammount of coal to burn
   var burn = prompt("How much coal do you want to burn?");
   burn = Number(burn);

   if (burn > coal)
     burn = coal;

   if (-burn > coal)
     burn = -coal;


   if (burn >= 0)
     coal = coal - burn;
   else
     coal = coal + burn;

   speed = speed + gravity - burn;

   height = height - speed; 
}

document.write("</p>");

drawSky(ctx);
drawGround(ctx);


if (speed <= maxSpeedForSafeLanding) {
   drawRocket(ctx, 0);

   document.write("<p>Congratulations Captain " + name + ".  You landed safely with a speed of " + speed + "m/s and you still have " + coal + "kg of coal left.</p>");
} else {
   drawExplosion(ctx, 25+coal*2+speed*2);

   document.write("<p>Rest In Peace Captain " + name + ".  You crashed with a speed of " + speed + "m/s and you still had " + coal + "kg of coal left.You will be burried on the planet you crashed on.</p>");
}

drawCoalBar(ctx, coal);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Rocket Lander Game</h1>

<canvas id="gameview" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

<script>
main();
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: var rocket = new Image();

rocket.src = "rocket.jpg";
rocket.onload = main(rocket);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var rocket = new Image();
rocket.onload = function(){ main(rocket) };
rocket.src = "rocket.jpg";
```

Comment: You should add some details about the solution, to explain to the author of the question.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that you are invoking the function `main()` and the *result* of `main` is given to the `onload` instead.

You can simply write it as this to give a *reference* to `main` instead::

```
rocket.onload = main;  //main will be invoked when image is loaded
```

or

```
rocket.onload = function(e) { main() };
```

In the latter we give an *anonymous* function as argument and when that is called `main()` gets invoked inside of it. This is useful if you want to do other things with the image before calling `main()`.

As `rocket` is globally available in this case there is no need to give it as argument to `main` but if you need to call `main` with other images this is of course a good way of doing it. But you can then add a argument variable to main:

```
function main(image) {

    /// ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0); etc..
}
```

Also consider to implement an `onerror` callback handler for image in case something goes wrong duing image loading.